# .NET 3.5 Reflection Help

Tags: vb.net, reflection

Sup Guys,

On my Bussiness Layer, I have something like

```
Dim object as New ExampleObject
```

Where `ExampleObject` inherits `BaseExampleObject`.

I want to know how can I access `ExampleObject` Properties by reflection on my `BaseExampleObject`.

Something like:

```
MyBase.GetType.GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(mybase.gettype, Nothing)
```

Of course thats not going to work because this is not an instance of an object and if I instantiate a new object, I'll lose the reference from my Bussiness Layer.

Anyone got a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cast your BaseExampleObject to ExampleObject:

```
BaseExampleObject b;
b = new ExampleObject();
((ExampleObject)b).Something();
```

Comment: BaseExampleObject is a mustinherit class wich i got some common methods for a lot of classes (thats why i need to access their propreties thru reflection), and also, cast an already inherited object is kinda a WOP.